# Why are arrays not saveable in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I know that sql can't save arrays (correct me if i'm wrong).
why?
I know this is a stupid question, but
Arrays are only structured data. Why can't sql save that?

Can i rewrite my mysql database or download a Addon for sql so i can save arrays?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In SQL world you should normalize your data. Array is not atomic(you probably want to refer to specific element of array and not array as a whole). Anyway PostgresSQL/Oracle allow to store arrays.

Comment: If you want to use array you can use NOSQL

Comment: Sql Can store Serialized Data, E.G Json or XML, you can use that to save Arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relational database management systems (RDBMS), such as MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle and PostgreSQL usually store data in tables. This is a very good way to store related data.

Let's say there are three entities: customers, orders, and products, and the orders contain multiple products. Four tables hence:

- customers(customer_no, name)
- products(product_no, name, price)
- orders(order_no, customer_no, date)
- order_details(order_no, product_no, amount)

We would provide indexes (i.e. search trees) to easily find orders of a customer or products in an order. Now let's say, we want to know how many orders have been made for product 123:

```
select count(distinct order_no)
from order_details
where product_no = 123;
```

The DBMS will quickly find the order_detail records for the product, because looking up an index is like searching by last name in a telephone book (binary search). And then it's mere counting. So only few records get read and the whole query is really fast.

Now the same with arrays. Something like:

```
products(product_no, name, price)

customers
(
  customer_no,
  name, 
  array of orders
  (
    order_no, 
    date,
    array of products
    (
      product_no,
      amount
    )
  )
)
```

Well, the order details are now hidden inside an order element which itself is inside a customer object. To get the number of orders for product 123, the only approach seems to be to read *all* customer records, loop through *all* orders and see whether they contain the product. This can take awfully long. Moreover without foreign key constraints for the relations between the entities, the arrays may contain product numbers that don't even exist.

Well, there may be ways to kind of index array data and there may be ways to guarantee data consistency for them, but the relational approach with tables has proven to solve these things extremely well. So we would avoid arrays and rather build our relations with tables instead. This is what a relational database is made for.

(Having said this, arrays may come in handy every now and then, e.g. in a recursive query were you want to remember which records have already been visited, but these occasions are rare.)

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, i first want to thank for the comments
THANK YOU!
back to the question: ordinary sql cant save arrays and doesnt want to save save, because of [normalization](https://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/normalization) issues.

you can save arrays on another way:
A SQL Table is like an array. Link a new table as array. Create the table manually or, if the array could change, with Code. There is no need for arrays in sql

If you have to do, or want to do so, you can use Nosql or PostgreSql or save the Data with JSON, Oracle and XML